# Installing Spacy with Conda on Mac

Tags: nlp, anaconda, conda, spacy

I am trying to download Spacy to my Jupyter Notebook using Conda with this line :

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
```

However it gives this error that I don't understand:

> WARNING conda.base.context:use_only_tar_bz2(632): Conda is
>   constrained to only using the old .tar.bz2 file format because you
>   have conda-build installed, and it is <3.18.3. Update or remove
>   conda-build to get smaller downloads and faster extractions.
>
> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
>
> Solving environment: failed
>
> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:
>
> - anaconda==2019.03=py37_0 -> anaconda-client==1.7.2=py37_0 -> nbformat -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
> - anaconda==2019.03=py37_0 -> importlib_metadata==0.8=py37_0
> - jsonschema - pkgs/main/osx-64::_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf==0.1.0=py37_0 -> ipywidgets
>     -> nbformat[version='>=4.2.0'] -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0'] - pkgs/main/osx-64::anaconda-client==1.7.2=py37_0 -> nbformat -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
>
>   - pkgs/main/osx-64::anaconda-navigator==1.9.7=py37_0 -> anaconda-client[version='>=1.6.14'] -> nbformat[version='>=4.4.0'] ->
>       jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
>   - pkgs/main/osx-64::importlib_metadata==0.8=py37_0 - pkgs/main/osx-64::ipywidgets==7.4.2=py37_0 ->
>       nbformat[version='>=4.2.0'] -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
>   - pkgs/main/osx-64::jupyter==1.0.0=py37_7 -> ipywidgets -> nbformat[version='>=4.2.0'] -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
>   - pkgs/main/osx-64::jupyterlab==0.35.4=py37hf63ae98_0 -> jupyterlab_server[version='>=0.2.0,<0.3.0'] -> notebook -> nbconvert
>       -> nbformat[version='>=4.4'] -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
>   - pkgs/main/osx-64::jupyterlab_server==0.2.0=py37_0 -> notebook -> nbconvert -> nbformat[version='>=4.4'] ->
>       jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
>   - pkgs/main/osx-64::nbconvert==5.4.1=py37_3 -> nbformat[version='>=4.4'] -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
>   - pkgs/main/osx-64::nbformat==4.4.0=py37_0 -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
>   - pkgs/main/osx-64::notebook==5.7.8=py37_0 -> nbconvert -> nbformat[version='>=4.4'] -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
>   - pkgs/main/osx-64::path.py==11.5.0=py37_0 -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.5']
>   - pkgs/main/osx-64::spyder==3.3.3=py37_0 -> nbconvert -> nbformat[version='>=4.4'] -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
>   - pkgs/main/osx-64::widgetsnbextension==3.4.2=py37_0 -> notebook[version='>=4.4.1'] -> nbconvert -> nbformat[version='>=4.4']
>       -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']

Any idea how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this warning with installation of Conda-build:

```
conda install conda-build
```

But I have same problem with installing opencv to my notebook and I don't know how to fix it so far:(

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it didn't work for some reason.